Docker container not updating when changing FROM
Consider the following dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

Running php -v in the resulting container, gives me 8.2.19. If I now change the php version to 8.3 and rebuild, the same command will still show me 8.2.19, indicating that the container didn't actually factor in the change I made. To get version 8.3 I have to delete the image and build it anew.
Why? Docker is usually pretty good about detecting changes in the dockerfiles. Why can't it handle this automatically?
Edit:
Here are the contents of the docker-compose.yml
services:
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: php_version_test
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"

which I build with docker-compose build && docker-compose -p test up -d

Please provide a [mcve] including the exact commands you used to build the image, run the container, and execute the command in the container.

It works for me. So either the commands you're running are not correct, or you get some error message.

Can you reproduce it without the dockerfile and volume mount? Just specify the image directly in the compose file and don't mount content that's not included in the question into the image.

Yes, it will work when adding the image in the compose file. I need the dockerfile to add some dependencies, which I removed for the example. I would expect the behavior to be the same if I change the image in the dockerfile, though.

And the volume mount?
